# How to read text and put it to an image in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, gcc, input, output

Below is the code that write text above image but i am looking for input output operation above image. I want that image as background image and all input output by user like `Enter your name`(output) and `my name is xyz`(input) should be done above image.Here i can use `cvPutText()` to write above image but how to get input from user. Any idea or suggestion are welcome ..

```
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
  IplImage* img = 0;
  img = cvLoadImage( "C:\\Dev-Cpp\\zzPograms\\cv\\152.jpg" );
  cvNamedWindow( "152.jpg", CV_WND_PROP_ASPECTRATIO );
  CvFont *font= new CvFont;
  cvInitFont(font,CV_FONT_VECTOR0,2.0f,4.0f,2,2,2);
  char text[10]="aboveimg"; 
  cvPutText(img,text,Point(100,250),font,CV_RGB(255,6,6));  // Put text on image
                             //what to do here for taking input from user like cin ??
  cvShowImage( "152.jpg", img );
  cvWaitKey(0);
  cvReleaseImage( &img );
  cvDestroyWindow( "152.jpg" );
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want the user to be able to write text onto the surface of the image? AFAIK, that is not possible.

Comment: Yes i want user to write text onto the surface of image

Comment: Please use the C++ interface of OpenCV. The [C interface is deprecated](http://answers.opencv.org/question/5421/which-one-is-preferred-to-use-c-or-c/) and may be removed in the future.

Comment: Not possible @uditr043 . What you can do is make a console app and echo the characters the user types on the console onto the image as he types them

Comment: Also, use the C++ interface as @nils says.

Comment: @AbhijatBiswas , yes that is the one possible way , thnx.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you want to put the text when your image has already been displayed **OR** you first want to take the input from User and then want to put it to the image.

**First case:**

1. Ask user to enter a string
2. Read that string
3. convert it to the char array
4. put it into char text[]
5. Rest of the things will remain same.

**Second Case:**
If you want to have a feeling that the user can write at the image then, do the following:

```
while(1)
{
    1. Read image
    2. char text[10];
    3. ask user to put the text
    4. read the text
    5. convert to the char form
    6. put the text on the image
    7. display the image
    8. waitKey(0);
}
```

in this way, user will be asked every time about the text he/she want to put on the image.

**I am not sure if you are really looking for it. It is just a concept.**

Comment: First i want to display image then first text will be shown on image 'enter your name' then user will enter his name above image. I think your second case is right but need to modify that i will do :)

Comment: @uditr043: yeah, second case will help you. It is just a template so, you need to modify it as per your requirement. Upvote/accept the answer if it is helpful to you.

Comment: Your profile pic is 'lena.jpg' so i think you are an expert in opencv .. is there any function (oppostie to puttext) which work as cin or scanf to retrieve data entered by user ABOVE image ?

Comment: @uditr043: In my knowledge, there is no such function but nobody is perfect. There are always some surprises. If you find any, please let the community know about it.

Comment: Yeah sure ! I will search for it.